Past vs future perfect continuous
I want to make myself sure about one thing. To me past and future perfect continuous are almost the same. One referring to the past the other to the future. I see many examples where past perfect is used with no duration stated for instance " I had been working when my mother came by". On the other hand with future perfect continuous the duration is almost always stated. That's my question. Do you  think it is okay to use that tense without providing information about the duration? Let's use the same example "I will have been working when my mother comes by". Possible? If not why? How come it is perfectly fine to use past perfect without duration if (possibly) I have to include one while using the future perfect continuous?

You're on the right track. Converting expressions to future is a very big change, mostly because the future is unknown and not fixed. It's an odd way to think of it to say "I have to include a duration," though; it's more that I have no reason to use this construction without one.

The whole point of future perfect continuous is about imagining something that has not yet happened. That's why you see when or by in those utterances.

OP's query:

Let's use the same example "I will have been working when my mother arrives". Possible?

Yes, it is possible and grammatically correct. In fact this explanation applies for your previous query on  "Perfect Continuous infinitive" also.
Past Perfect Continuous
often doesn't require a specific duration, as in your example:
"I had been working when my mother came by." (No duration stated)
This is because the focus is on the completed action (working) before another action in the past (mother's arrival).
On the other hand, Future Perfect Continuous  typically requires a specific duration or time frame to indicate the ongoing action up to a point in the future:

"I will have been working for 3 hours when my mother comes by." (Duration stated).

However, it's not strictly necessary to include a duration with Future Perfect Continuous. (This holds true for Perfect Continuous infinitive also)

"He'll have still been eating when she got there last night." Notice there's nothing "future" about that.

@tchrist OP's sentence is  "I will have been working when my mother comes by".. It is future tense. Where is got or came. I referred to a similar query by OP earlier.
